# Hyva React Checkout is not showing in frontend in Magento 2

Tags: reactjs, magento, magento2

I am working on Hyva React checkout along with Hyva Theme for a page and created a custom module for checkout. However it showing up like so in frontend -

[image: Screenshot of Hyva Checkout Frontend]

There is no products showing up here which were added in the cart. I have tried all the steps from the [documentation](https://hyva-themes.github.io/magento2-react-checkout/installation/) with the first method of customization. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps

```
1.composer require hyva-themes/magento2-react-checkout
2.bin/magento s:up
3.bin/magento config:set hyva_react_checkout/general/enable 1
```

check the checkout page after run this commands.